# "Docker redis error": connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379

Tags: docker

###############

Docker file

###############

```
FROM node:alpine

WORKDIR '/app'

COPY package.json .

RUN yarn

COPY . .

CMD ["yarn","run","start"]
```

###################

docker-compose.yml

###################

```
version: '3'

services:

  redis-server:

    image: 'redis'

  node-app:

    build: .
    
    ports:
    
     - "8081:8081"
```

---------------------------app.js---------------------------------------

```
const express = require('express');

const redis = require('redis');

const app = express();

const client = redis.createClient({
  host:'localhost',
  port: 6379
});

client.set('visits', 0);

app.get('/', (req, res) => { client.get('visits', (err, visits) => { res.send('Number of visits is ' + visits); client.set('visits', parseInt(visits) + 1); }); });

app.listen(8081, () => { console.log('Listening on port 8081'); });
```

##################################

Error message

##################################

> node:events:346
> throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
> ^
>
> Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379

Comment: You must explain what the issue you are experiencing is, otherwise it will be closed after a while.

Answer (score 5):

As I see from `app.js` code, you're trying to access one docker container from another by using `localhost`, which is wrong. Docker-compose creates a network for your services and gives them hostname equal to service name by default. You can reference [docker compose networking documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) for more details.

So, you should access redis service from your app by `redis-server` host instead of `localhost`.

Also, there is no exposed redis port in your docker-compose file. It should look like

```
version: '3'
services:
  redis-server:
   image: 'redis'
     - "6379:6379"
  node-app:
   build: .
   ports:
     - "8081:8081"
```

And your application should create redis connection next way:

```
const client = redis.createClient({ host:'redis-server', port: 6379 });
```

Comment: hi just i am following your answer but its didnt workout... my email id : hemanand5303@gmail.com kindly send any code sample for nodejs with redis using docker....

i am using docker build this step only 
-------------------------------------------------
docker build -t myapp .